# How can I add jQuery (SharePoint 2010)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I have a HTML page that I need to be linked to within our organization's SharePoint 2010 portal. I have all needed files (CSS, images, jquery) stored in the same document library. The CSS seems to be working fine but I'm having trouble getting the jQuery to work. Any suggestions or thoughts on what could be the issue here? Thank you.

**Update: The HTML page consists of one image (image map) that I have sectioned into 100 or so clickable areas. When clicked, a jQuery plugin activates and (SHOULD) display a tooltip directly to the right of the clickable area. My issue is that the tooltip is being displayed to the right of the WHOLE image instead. So I think I was wrong in my initial question about the jQuery not working. The tooltip plugin indeed activates, it is just appearing outside the image instead of on top of the image where it should be. This works properly in a local environment but once the files are uploaded to the SharePoint server this behavior happens. Is there some internal JS/CSS files within SharePoint that I can/need to override? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Need some more details, is jQuery not loading at all? Or just errors calling jQuery functions? I'm guessing you're getting errors calling jQuery functions. You'll want to use jQuery.noConflict(); to prevent conflicts with SharePoint javascript functions. The $ symbol that jQuery uses by default is also used by SharePoint. So you call jQuery.noConflict(); at the top of your javascript, and then you just swap using the $ for calling jQuery functions to just writing jQuery. So $(document).ready becomes jQuery(document).ready. $.ajax becomes jQuery.ajax, and so on.

[jQuery.noConflict Details](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)